# How to get Mac OS X text substitutions working on Thunderbird

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, thunderbird

Is there a way to get this working on Thunderbird? When I right-click on the email message window, the popup menu doesn't include the usual Mac items (Substitutions, Transformations, etc…)

Comment: Is your title complete or is there a word missing?

Comment: The cost of cross-plattform software.

Comment: @Doug Fixed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible. The additional text field options are available to programs that use the Cocoa APIs to interface with Mac OS X and Thunderbird doesn't use them (part of it's cross platform compatibility choice).

You can however use an alternative program such as TypeIt4Me or TextExpander which will work with every program instead of just those that leverage the built-in features of Mac OS X.

Comment: Do you know more about this? I dug through the Mozilla sources (their FTP was down, so it was a bit limited) after I read this question, and they actually subclass `NSTextView` as `widget/src/cocoa/ComplexTextInputPanel` (but I don't know how they use it) which afaik is the widget supporting the OP's features.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: I don't recall off hand. I know they have moved to using Cocoa widgets but have not added support for the features that the widget can bring along free of charge. Exactly why I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Btw, the software is called `TypeIt4Me`, your suggestion, while creative, produces 0 google hits.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: oops. Thanks for the typo catch. I'm a former TypeIt4Me user. (Don't really use it anymore)